# Getting an Error for BERT module when trying to access bert.variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I'm trying to get BERT to do sentiment analysis from the code obtained from here: https://github.com/strongio/keras-bert

But when I try to build the model, I get an error saying,

```
'Module' object has no attribute 'variables'
```

This occurs specifically in the build function of the BertLayer class when I try to access self.bert.variables.

I tried a `dir(self.bert)` to get all the attributes of the object and it indeed did not have an attribute called variables. These are the attributes I obtained:

```
['\__call__', '\__class__', '\__delattr__', '\__dict__', '\__dir__', '\__doc__', '\__eq__', '\__format__', '\__ge__', '\__getattribute__', '\__gt__', '\__hash__', '\__init__', '\__init_subclass__', '\__le__', '\__lt__', '\__module__', '\__ne__', '\__new__', '\__reduce__', '\__reduce_ex__', '\__repr__', '\__setattr__', '\__sizeof__', '\__str__', '\__subclasshook__', '\__weakref__', '_graph', '_impl', '_name', '_spec', '_tags', '_trainable', 'export', 'get_input_info_dict', 'get_output_info_dict', 'get_signature_names', 'variable_map']
```

I'm using tf version: 1.13.0 with Python: 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Installing the very latest versions of both tensorflow and tensorflow hub fixed this issue.